# How does PHP handle duplicated URL parameters?

Tags: php, http, get

Quick question: if I submit a form like the following

```
<form action='something.php'>
   <input type='text' name='a' />
   <input type='text' name='a' />
</form>
```

what would $_GET['a'] output?

Comment: PHPs default handler throws it away, but manually evaluating `QUERY_STRING` could recover duplicated params.

Comment: @itachi, not if I have to setup the server first! it's just a question that came up in the middle of a conversation, and I wanted to make sure...

Comment: It takes seconds to [set up a PHP server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) these days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the names end in `[]` it gives you an array, otherwise it gives you the last result.

Comment: Not necessarily the last result. AFAIK it depends on the user agent.

Comment: @PeeHaa — It doesn't. Clients send form data in the order in which it appears in the form. Once it hits the server, there are not UA differences.

Answer (score 2):

`$_GET['a']` would be the last or first parameter (I don't remember).

You have two options:

1. Either parse the string your self (can be done both with GET and POST)
2. use "a[]" as name. That will trigger PHP to populate `$_GET['a']` as an array. However, this behavior is not standard and might give you problems with client side javascripting.

For parsing, either use (for GET)

```
 $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

or (for POST)

```
 file_get_contents("php://input")
```

`php://input` is a stream which is equivalent to the raw body data of the request.